# Ternary in a 10-digit string

Tags: permutations, combinations

I encountered an interesting question and can't seem to form a logic for solving it.

> We need to form a 10-digit string using $0$, $1$, or $2$ (ternary string). There should be exactly $3$ 0's. In total, how many ways are there to form this string?

I know we must choose either $1$ or $2$ for the seven slots => $2^7$
For the $3$ 0's, we can place them in any of the $8$ spaces surrounding the seven slots. My initial idea was that this is $8\choose3$? And so the answer will be the multiplication of these $2$ answers. However, when I try a similar questions on a smaller set of digit, my logic fails.

Anyone can help explain? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any 3 places for the zeros. This can be done in $\binom{10}{3}$ ways. The remaining 7 places can be either $1$ or $2$. This can be done $2^7$ ways. So the answer is
$$
\binom{10}{3}\, 2^7 = 61440$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  First choose the slots for the zeros.  How many ways can you do that?  Then you need to fill the rest with $1$'s and $2$'s.  How many ways? Multiply